# max not working on series/list inside of for loop

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have the following function written to find the most recent date in my dataset prior to the year I am calculating for. I am having trouble understanding why it will not work in a for loop, but it will outside of one. If I write it with a hardcoded value as the year, it will run just fine. However, when I try to put it in a loop, it will give the following error:

> 'ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence'

Thank you for any insight on why this is error is thrown, and what I can do to fix it.

```
def max_date_prior_to_year(dates, yr):
     return max(dates[dates<pd.to_datetime(str(yr)+'-01-01')])

print(max_date_prior_to_year(df['Date'], 2014))
2013-10-15 00:00:00

for yr in [2011,2012,2013,2014]:
    print(max_date_prior_to_year(df['Date'], yr))
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your code fails where `df` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You are comparing apples and oranges

`max_date_prior_to_year(df['Date'], 2014)` feeds `2014` as the `yr` argument. But your `for` loop starts with `2011`. If `df['Date']` has no dates  before 1st January 2011, `dates[dates<pd.to_datetime(str(yr)+'-01-01')]` will return an empty series, so you are effectively calculating:

```
max(pd.Series())  # ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

> If the iterable is empty and default is not provided, a `ValueError`
>   is raised.

#### Use `pd.Series.max` instead of built-in `max`

One way you can avoid `ValueError` and increase efficiency is to use [`pd.Series.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html) instead of Python's built-in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max).<sup>1</sup> This is will return `NaN` if the series is empty after Boolean indexing. So change your function to:

```
def max_date_prior_to_year(dates, yr):
     return dates[dates<pd.to_datetime(str(yr)+'-01-01')].max()
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, as a rule you should prefer Pandas numeric methods to applying built-in functions on pandas series.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will use this in the future.

Comment: Sorry. I just signed up as a user on here, and this was my first question. I clocked the green check mark, and will remember this for the future. Thanks again for your help!